# How to fix .htaccess in order to deny index.php file to be downloaded (in Yii2)?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii2

There is a Yii2 project. And I needed to make temporary redirect from domain `sitename.ru` to subdomain `ru.sitename.com` for all pages, except some ones (which begins with `/news`). I've made the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 25M
php_value memory_limit 256M

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news.*$
RewriteRule (.*) http://ru.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

As a result all redirects works properly. But when I try to open pages which begins with `/news`, then the `index.php` file downloading process starts. How can I fix this one?
Thanks in advance!

**UPD 1**
 
Apache settings are following:

```
<Directory /path/to/web/dir/www/sitename.ru/web>
    Options +ExecCGI
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/path/to/web/dir:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp"
    php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>

<VirtualHost 1.11.11.111:81>
    ServerName sitename.ru
    DocumentRoot /path/to/web/dir/www/sitename.ru/web
    SuexecUserGroup admin admin 
    CustomLog /path/to/httpd-logs/sitename.ru.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /path/to/httpd-logs/sitename.ru.error.log
    ServerAlias www.sitename.ru
    ServerAdmin email@yandex.exo
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /path/to/web/dir/www/sitename.ru/web/cgi-bin/
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/path/to/web/dir:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp"
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f email@yandex.exo"
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/path/to/web/dir/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value session.save_path "/path/to/web/dir/mod-tmp"
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    AddHandler php5-script .php
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPD 2**
 
I've mentioned that the same situation had place for all php files (if ones were in the web dir).That's why I've updated Apache settings with the following string:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

And now php files works properly. But the problem (regarding the `/news` path) I've described still has place.

Comment: Sounds like the apache config is not setup to properly handle PHP files.

Comment: @user3137702 I've updated my question and added Apache code

Comment: The server that is initiating a "download" of index.php does not have the PHP module properly configured, so it is being sent as a file rather than executed.

Comment: @user3409477 By the way, I've mentioned that the same situation had place for all php files (if ones were in the web dir). In order to fix it I've added a new string to Apache config: `AddHandler php5-script .php` And now php files works properly. But the problem (regarding the **/news** path) I've described still has place.

Comment: You said that the /news path is now being handled by another server, so that server probably needs a similar configuration change.